# Kubernetes load balance HTTP/1.1 requests

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, http-1.1

As we know, by default HTTP 1.1 uses persistent connections which is a long-lived connection. For any service in [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), for example, clusterIP mode, it is L4 based load balancer.

Suppose I have a service which is running a web server, this service contains 3 pods, I am wondering whether HTTP/1.1 requests can be distributed to 3 pods?

Could anybody help clarify it?

Comment: A set of requests that uses a single long-lived connection will go to the same pod. A different set of requests that uses a different long-lived connection might be distributed to another pod.

Comment: Is it possible that a set of requests that uses a single long-lived connection can be distributed evenly to different pods?

Comment: A connection is an established channel between the client application and the server application (i.e. the application instance running inside the container inside the pod), so it does not make sense for the server application side to switch to another instance while the connection has already been established. If we are to engineer such magic then Kubernetes somehow has to simulate the TCP handshakes (SYN, SYN-ACK,ACK) for the application instance that the connection would need to transfer to in order to make the client assume it is still talking to the same server application instance.

Comment: Do you know under what circumstances HTTP/1.1 long-lived connection will be disconnected?

Comment: HTTP is just another layer on top of TCP so to close an HTTP connection, either the client or the server application needs to send a FIN packet. In HTTP 1.0, the server application will always send the FIN packet to close the connection after a single request-response cycle. In HTTP 1.1, either the client closes the connection or the server application can also close the connection due to KeepAliveTimeout setting or if the server application shuts down for whatever reason.

Comment: I want to mark the issue as solved, seem I could not perform because the answer is under my question tress, could you move your answer to "Answer" instead of comments?

Answer (score 3):

This webpage perfectly address your question: https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-long-lived-connections

In the spirit of StackOverflow, let me summarize the webpage here:

1. TLDR: Kubernetes doesn't load balance long-lived connections, and some Pods might receive more requests than others.
2. Kubernetes Services do not exist. There's no process listening on the IP address and port of a Service.
3. The Service IP address is used only as a placeholder that will be translated by iptables rules into the IP addresses of one of the destination pods using cleverly crafted randomization.
4. Any connections from clients (regardless from inside or outside cluster) are established directly with the Pods, hence for an HTTP 1.1 persistent connection, the connection will be maintained between the client to a specific Pod until it is closed by either side.
5. Thus, all requests that use a single persistent connection will be routed to a single Pod (that is selected by the iptables rule when establishing connection) and not load-balanced to the other Pods.

Additional info:

By W3C RFC2616 (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.3), any proxy server that serves between client and server must maintain HTTP 1.1 persistent connections from client to itself and from itself to server.