# Non uniform distribution of requests between internal services in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube, kubernetes-service

I have 2 different microservices deployed as backend in minikube, call it deployment A and deployment B. Both these deployments have a different replica of pods running.

Deployment B is exposed as service B. Pods of deployment A call deployment B pods via service B which is of ClusterIP type.

The pods of deployment B have a scrapyd application running inside them with scraping spiders deployed in them. Each celery worker( pods of deployment A) takes a task from a redis queue and calls scrapyd service to schedule spiders on them.

Everything works fine but after I scale the application (deployment A and B seperately),  I observe that the resource consumption is not uniform, using `kubectl top pods`
I observe that some of the pods of deployment B are not used at all. The pattern I observe is that only those pods of deployment B, that are up and running after all the pods of deployment A are up, are never utilized.

Is it normal behavior? I suspect the connection between pods of deployment A and B is persistent I am confused as to why request handling by pods of deployment B is not uniformly distributed? Sorry for the naive question. I am new to this field.

The manifest for **deployment A** is :

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: celery-worker
  labels:
    deployment: celery-worker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: celery-worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod: celery-worker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: celery-worker
          image: celery:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          command: ['celery', '-A', 'mysite', 'worker', '-E', '-l', 'info',]
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 200
```

and that of **deployment B** is

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: scrapyd
  labels:
    app: scrapyd
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: scrapyd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod: scrapyd
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: scrapyd
          image: scrapyd:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6800
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 800m
            requests:
              cpu: 800m
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 100

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: scrapyd
spec:
  selector:
    pod: scrapyd
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 6800
    targetPort: 6800
```

Output of `kubectl top pods` :

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include more information about your setup. Mainly, the `Deployment` manifests, the `$ kubectl top pod` (to show the differences between `Pods`),  what exactly your `Pods` in `Deployment B` are configured to do?

Comment: @ Dawid Kruk I updated the question with required manifests. The pods of deployment B have a scrapyd application running inside them with scraping spiders deployed in them. Each celery worker takes a task from a redis queue and calls scrapyd service.

Comment: Apologies for late reply. I can't tell from the perspective of `scrapyd` and `celery` as this technologies are unknown to me but it could be possible that the `celery-worker-X` connected to `scrapyd-X` is a persistent connection (from software perspective of those 2 technologies) and that would not be changed even when scaling of `Deployment B` occurs i.e: `A-x` would send the data only to `B-x`.  Basing on your other questions (`http keep-alive in scrapyd`), I'd reckon this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66002726/12257134

Comment: @Dawid Kruk Thanks for the answer. I also read about the same and i guess this was only happening. Due to that persistent TCP connection default load balancing at layer 4 done by Kube proxy was not working. I was able to fix the issue by injecting the celery deployment with linkerd proxy to perform layer 7 routing. It is working smoothly now !

Comment: I'm glad that you resolved your question. Please post it as an answer so that the community could benefit from your research if it stumbles upon same issue.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution to the above problem that I figured out is as follows :

In the current setup, install linkerd using this link. [Linkerd Installation in Kubernetes](https://linkerd.io/2/getting-started/)

After that inject the linkerd proxy into celery deployment as follows :

```
cat celery/deployment.yaml | linkerd inject - | kubectl apply -f -
```

This ensures that the requests from celery are first passed on to this proxy and then Load balanced directly to scrapy at L7 Layer. In this case, kube-proxy is by passed and the default load balancing over L4 is no longer functional.